# Webpack Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, webpack, handlebars.js

When I run the 'webpack' command, I get this error:

ERROR in ./js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '...\js' @ ./js/main.js 3:0-16 4:0-23

In package.json I have:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "handlebars": "^4.0.6",
   "handlebars-loader": "^1.4.0",
   "jquery": "^3.2.1",
   "path": "^0.12.7"
},
```

In webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./js/main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/js",
    filename: "scripts-bundled.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, "js/helpers")
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-loader"}
    ]
  }
};
```

And in main.js at the top of the file, I have:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

I'm also using handlebars in main.js. Could it be that handlebars or handlebars-loader is interfering with the jquery? I've used webpack and jquery without this issue before in another project where I didn't use handlebars, but maybe it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: as far i know, you should use JQLITe for using jquery with webpack

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The handlebars has nothing to do with it. The problem is that you changed [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) to `[path.join(__dirname, "js/helpers")]`. So webpack will only look in `js/helpers` for any module, but `jquery` and other dependencies from npm are in `node_modules`. The default value of `resolve.modules` is `["node_modules"]`. You also need to add `node_modules` to keep the regular module resolution.

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.join(__dirname, "js/helpers"),
    "node_modules"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 29):

resolve error using following command.
`npm install --save jquery`

Comment: If you're using npm >5.0.0, the `--save` flag is not necessary.

Answer (score 18):

Well in my case it was something about importing **jquery** instead of **jQuery**, it is a webpack config:

```
externals: {
    // require("jquery") is external and available
    //  on the global var jQuery
    "jquery": "jQuery"
}
```

have a look at this:
[webpack Can't resolve 'jquery'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330231/webpack-cant-resolve-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React with Bootstrap and you're getting this error, it may be because you're using the lower version of Bootstrap. I solved it by upgrading the version to Bootstrap version 5.

Answer (score 0):

If using mac OSX, npm version 5.0.0 or greater, try this command on your project folder terminal: `npm install jquery jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6 : `yarn add jquery` work for me

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.