# webpack - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, webpack, sails.js

I'm using Sails 1 with webpack and when I attempt to import jquery from my main js file, I get this error yelling that it can't resolve jquery.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports.webpack = {

    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        'admin': './assets/admin/js/admin.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.tmp', 'public')
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "js"), "node_modules"
        ]
    },
    module: {
        // Extract less files
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader' })
        }, {
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader!less-loader' })
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { 
                presets: [ 
                    [ 'es2015', { modules: false } ] 
                ] 
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
        // This plugin extracts CSS that was imported into .js files, and bundles
        // it into separate .css files.  The filename is based on the name of the
        // .js file that the CSS was imported into.
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].bundle.css'),

        // This plugin cleans out your .tmp/public folder before lifting.
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public'], {
            root: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.tmp'),
            verbose: true,
            dry: false
        }),

        // This plugin copies the `images` and `fonts` folders into
        // the .tmp/public folder.  You can add any other static asset
        // folders to this list and they'll be copied as well.
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: './assets/images',
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.tmp', 'public', 'images')
        }])
    ]
};
```

and in my assets/admin/js/admin.js I only have

```
import 'jquery';
```

jquery is on my package json and it shows up under my node_modules packages with the name *jquery*.

Another weird thing is that if I change jquery and attempt to import **angular**, it **works** perfectly, so I don't think it's a node_modules directory issue or something like that.

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198547/webpack-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-jquery

Comment: @jimcollins I saw that answer, but since angular is working fine and is installed via npm just like jquery, it seems like it might be something different, am I missing something?

Comment: The config looks alright, I don't think it's webpack related. Maybe the module wasn't installed correctly. Can you run `node -e 'require("jquery")'`? If that throws an error, you should delete `node_modules` and re-install them.

Comment: it trhows an error,
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'

but I dont understand, it shows up under the node_modules and when I installed it it didnt throw any error. I tried removing the entire folder and installing it again and same thing happens

Comment: I've heard that people had some issues with npm 5. Either try upgrading it or downgrading to 4 with `npm install -g npm@4`. After that you could also delete the cache (which might pull in the same broken package) with `npm cache clean`, before re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

A different issue brought me here. For future visitors coming from Google, try running:

```
webpack --display-error-details
```