# webpack Can't resolve 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, webpack

Hi I'm a new to Webpack , currently I'm adding this tool to my project, during bundling (webpack ...) jquery-dependent library I get an error like that:

> Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'C:\some_folder'

I browsed through similar posts on internet with no positive effect.
People recommend using different approaches like :
 - resolve.alias
 - plugins  ProvidePlugin

I use webpack 3.3.0, in my project **jQuery** is loaded in normal way via **script tag** before vendor bundle scripts.
Most of vendor librairies including jQuery live not in node_modules folder.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = env => {
    return {
        context: resolve('src'),
        entry: {
            comp: './start.comp.js',
            culture: './start.culture.js',
            strategy: './start.strategy.js',
            vendors: './start.vendors.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: resolve('dist'),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: 'bundle.[name].js'
        },
        devtool: env.dev ? 'eval' : 'source-map'
    };
};
```

**the last entry jquery.placeholder.min.js is a problem**

```
require('./../assets/vendor/typeahead.js');
require('./../assets/vendor/hogan-2.0.0.js');
require('./../assets/vendor/swfobject.js');
require('expose-loader?_!./../assets/vendor/underscore-min.js');
require('expose-loader?FastClick!./../assets/vendor/fastclick.js');
require('expose-loader?AOS!./../assets/vendor/aos.js');
require('./../assets/vendor/jquery.placeholder.min.js');
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use library in script tag with webpack because webpack should resolve all dependencies.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Problem

Since `jquery.placholder.min.js` is using UMD as its loading strategy, it's recognizing that it is required via a `require` - and tries to require jQuery in the same way:

```
"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?require("jquery"):jQuery
```

Webpack sees `require("jquery")` and tries to bundle the jQuery library (which does not exist in the node_modules).

#### Solution

The solution is to add jQuery as an [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  ...
  externals: {
    // require("jquery") is external and available
    //  on the global var jQuery
    "jquery": "jQuery"
  }
}
```

When a module is marked as an *external*, Webpack knows not to bundle it, but instead use the global variable.

Comment: For me, this allows build to complete, but causes this error on frontend `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`, I include jQuery with this in `webpack.config.js`:  `plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin(), new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: "./jquery-3.3.1", jQuery: "./jquery-3.3.1"}) ]`

Comment: Brilliant, this works! Many thanks. So it just uses the version that is installed and referenced via package.json

Answer (score 1):

I was working in react i have found that when i import the *react-bootstrap* components sometimes the components come like {Buttons} from ***bootstarp***; then i got this error. But i solved it by calling the path from ***bootstrap*** to ***react-bootstrap***;

Check your auto import call and try changing it. this worked for me.