# webpack: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui-bundle'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In React, I'm including jQuery UI like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import "jquery-ui-bundle";
```

When I run the code I get

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui-bundle' in '/usr/src/app/frontend'
```

Comment: Can you try to run `npm i jquery-ui-bundle` if it solves the issue?

Comment: What?!? I already have it installed. My app is running fine. This issue is only with webpack.

Comment: Take a look at the solution here and see if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330231/webpack-cant-resolve-jquery

Comment: I already did that to fix the issue in case of jquery. Earlier I had errors with both jquery and jquery-ui